# ResnetV2 Graph is messy

Tags: tensorflow, tensorboard

I am training a model using the official ResnetV2 implementation from here:
https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/official/resnet

When viewing the graph in Tensorboard, all the nodes are scattered and it's impossible to see the networks structure.

This is what it looks like:

[image: ResnetV2 Graph]

The entire graph is 100x as wide.

Any idea how to fix this? I would like to be able to discern the structure of the network.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to use "ungroup this set of nodes" for all ops that have been grouped together.